# Need a Sample Application to connect, retrieve and Send data to health vault site

Tags: asp.net

Hi need a sample Application to connect to the **Microsoft HealthVault** platform where I need the Following things to be done:

1. Application should Send and store the data in the health vault site.
2. Application should retrieve the data from the health vault site to my application.

Answer (score 0):

Eric Gunnerson has a long tutorial series on this.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2009/01/08/introduction-to-healthvault-development-1-introduction.aspx

Comment: hi Thanks for your reply. But i need the sample application which works in the offline Mode. The application you posted is Hello world which works in online ie., it will ask for the credentials every time